Is there a way to force git to commit an unchanged file?
I know that this is not normal practice and that my question is a "long shot". But is there a way force git to commit an unchanged file, so as to run githooks when the commit is pushed to GitHub, as well as for other post processing.  I need git log <file> to show the commit in the file's change history even though the file wasn't changed.
I've tried changing the file's timestamp via touch <file> and permissions via chmod <new-mode> <file>, but git add still fails to add the file to the index and git commit reports "nothing to commit".  This is on Linux, specifically on Ubuntu 24.04.

this sounds like an x-y problem. What are you trying to sovle exactly by using your githooks ?

Git stores snapshots. If the file hasn't changed, there's no new snapshot to store. What you can do is create an empty commit (git commit --allow-empty), but this will not show in the log when filtered to the file's path, because the file hasn't changed.
If you need the file changed, your only option is to actually change the file (e.g. add a newline at the end, a space character somewhere)

It's not so much "if the file hasn't changed, there's no snapshot to store" as it is "If the file hasn't changed, the new snapshot contains a file identical to the previous snapshot." git log looks for snapshot-to-snapshot changes, so if you want it to show up in git log, there has to be a change. What the git hook uses to decide what processing to do depends on the hook.

@RaymondChen note that my answer states "if the file hasn't changed, there's no new snapshot to store". The snapshot is identical to the previous snapshot, so there are no "changes".

There could be changes to other files in the repo, so you still get a snapshot (but the file in question is the same as in the previous snapshot). Maybe I'm just being too pedantic.
